# Problems with opening the link on another page

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink

I am working on contact page where the client can enter the postcode which will take them to google maps for directions to the company, the problem which i am having is although the hyperlink is set to target_blank but still the window opens on the back hand instead of opening in front of the website page. I have no idea why it opens on the back hand and focus is on the current page instead of moving it to google map page

```
  <a href="#" target="_blank">
               <img alt="" src="/images/contactUs/directionbtn.png" onclick="return openDirections(1);"  /></a>
<script type="text/javascript">

function openDirections(NumVal) {

    if (NumVal == 1) {

        if (document.getElementById("<%=txtPostcode.ClientID%>").value == "") {
            alert("PostCode can not be blank");
            document.getElementById("<%=txtPostcode.ClientID%>").focus();
            return false;
        }
        else {

            var regPostcode = /^([a-zA-Z]){1}([0-9][0-9]|[0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]|[a-zA-Z][0-9]){1}([ ])([0-9][a-zA-z][a-zA-z]){1}$/;
            var tempURL = document.getElementById("<%=txtPostcode.ClientID%>").value;
            if (regPostcode.test(tempURL) == false) {
                alert("Please Enter a Valid PostCode");
                document.getElementById("<%=txtPostcode.ClientID%>").focus();
                return false;
            }
            else {
                var url = 'http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr={' + $('#<%=txtPostcode.ClientID%>').val() + '}&daddr=&daddr=646+Preston+Rd,+Clayton-le-Woods,+Chorley+PR6+7EH,+United+Kingdom&iwloc=1&dq=Tangent+Design';


                document.location = url;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: What does "opens on the back hand" mean? And this looks like JavaScript to me!

Comment: the page doesnt loads in front of the website like it should

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `window.open(url);` instead of of `document.location = url;`

Comment: window.open(url); opens the same page twice instead of going to google maps

Comment: Then your function might be called twice. You can check this easily by adding alert("This popup should only appear once."); in your openDirections function.

Comment: Btw, from where is openDirections called?

Comment: have included <a> in the question

Comment: Try removing the surrounding <a> tag and just use this html: <img alt="" src="/images/contactUs/directionbtn.png" onclick="return openDirections(1);"  /> and also change
document.location = url;
return true;

to 

document.location = url;
return false;

Comment: how can i set a cursor property on it without adding extra css?

Comment: without adding extra css? Hm, why can't you use css? You can do it inline if you want. Like this <img style="cursor:pointer;" />

Answer (score 1):

All I see you doing is setting the url of the current window. Maybe try using something like this to open a new window instead.

```
window.open('url to open',)
```

in place of `document.location = url`

Comment: window.open(url); opens the same page twice instead of going to google maps

Comment: @Muhammad Awais If it is opening the same page, that says you might be setting the url incorrectly.

Comment: i just changed it to window.open(url);

Comment: @Muhammad Awais I just tried it. Here is the jsfiddle. It opens to google maps just fine. Something else is amiss here.  http://jsfiddle.net/mEw6J/

Comment: i tried this, which doesnt works  var url = 'http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?saddr={' + $('#<%=txtPostcode.ClientID%>').val() + '}&daddr=&daddr=646+Preston+Rd,+Clayton-le-Woods,+Chorley+PR6+7EH,+United+Kingdom&iwloc=1&dq=Tangent+Design';


                    window.open(url);

Comment: same issue , on firefox , 2 tabs of contactus page opens on clicking the get direction button . I just dont know what to do :(

Comment: have included <a> in the question

Comment: @Muhammad aaaah the <a> tag is definitely the issue. Just checked back to see someone else helped you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Each browser can be configured to handle how new pages are opened. Take a look at the preferences in the browser you are using, and see if that is the behavior that you currently have configured.

Comment: i have checked on all the browsers , the result is same

Comment: does it open in a tab or a seperate window?

Comment: this is probably a configuration in your browser. did you try looking in the config of whatever browser you are using? In IE 8, what i have to use at work, it is under Tools -> Internet Options -> Settings (under the Tabs heading). In that window, you will see a setting, always switch to new tabs when they are created; check it.

Comment: the new tab box is selected .. I m using chrome

Comment: Looks like chrome may not support opening in the foreground by default - http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=18a4eca148c306ba&hl=en. I don't have it at work to test.

Comment: i tried on firefox , 2 tabs get opened on clicking on get direction button one with google map while other one loads the same page again

Comment: do they open in the foreground as you want, or in the background?

Comment: either way, each consumer of your web app will have their own configuration. you will not be able to override that. As long as it is opening in a new window or tab, I think you are good.

Comment: in the background, i checked on another machine too with no success

Comment: do you have the option to open in front set - http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Options%20window%20-%20Tabs%20panel?

Comment: have included <a> in the question

Comment: if you really want it to always load in front, you should look at using jquery to load a dialog on your page (I suggest Jquery UI - http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
var x = window.open(URL, 'name', '...');
x.focus();
```